# Is there an Excel macro that checks that every row has a unique or blank number

Tags: vba, excel

What is an Excel macro that will check every cell in column A for whether they have unique numbers or are blank?

Comment: What do you have so far?

Comment: You can tell if you have dups by using Data|Filter|Advanced Filter and selecting "Unique records only". If any rows get filtered, you have dups.

Answer (score 0):

Does [this](http://www.vbaexpress.com/kb/getarticle.php?kb_id=985) do the job for you?